# anchors and regular links - styling

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

In a webpage I'm building I use anchors for easy navigating. The styling of these anchors in IE6 gives me some troubles.

```
<div class="text">
    <h3><a class="anchor" name="custom_name">Title</a></h3>
    Lorem ipsum <a href="otherpage.aspx">dolor</a> sit amet.
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.text 
{
    color: #000;
}

.text a[href] 
{
    color: #ea2026;  //red
}

.anchor, .anchor:hover
{
    color: #a9a18c;  //gray
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In FF and IE7+, no problems. But in IE6, the  links are white (as defined in the body selector) because it has issues with the .text a[href]. When I remove the [href] though, the anchors become red in all browsers (naturally). In firefox the hover still gives an effect, but not in IE.

Is there a way to style the anchors differently than the regular links in both FF and IE6? Obviously the class "anchor" doesn't help much...

**Edit** - Sorry, this is what I want:
All regular links have to be red (the href's). All the anchors have to be the h3 colour, gray. When I hover over a regular link it underlines, and a hover over one of the anchors should virtually change nothing.

Comment: What exactly do you want? - If you could sum up your color / effect needs in one or two sentences, that would help. example: "Ultimately, I want all anchors red, but if they don't have a href I want them purple" - or whatever :)

Comment: Agreed, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why do you need the [href] bit when you have the anchor class?

Comment: Using [href] instead of re-classing your anchors is good (and clear to  me), but I just want to know what you want as an end result for colors and style... then we can write the any-browser, best CSS for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... it's what I figured. See my response below (and don't add arbitrary classes when you don't need to :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the "anchor" class... I think what you want is this:

```
.text 
{
    color: #000;
}

.text a
{
    color: #ea2026; /*red*/
}

.text h3 a, .text h3 a:hover
{
    color: #a9a18c; /*gray*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Bingo, this is it. I failed to see the option of using h3 as a selector...  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
<h3><a class="anchor" name="custom_name">Title</a></h3>
```

With:

```
<h3 class="fragment" id="custom_name">Title</h3>
```

It is shorter, and doesn't get mixed up with styles intended for links.

(Alternatively, look at `a:link:hover, a:visited:hover {}`, but I don't know what IE is like about supporting multiple pseudo-classes on a single part of a selector)

Comment: I think you missed the point 100%... he wants anchors in the page so as to allow navigation... how would taking out the "a" tag help?

Comment: Surprisingly this does work actually. h3 tags with an id can be linked to... so this is indeed a lot cleaner! Never knew this :)

Comment: I would like to go on record as to eating my words :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.text > a` to hit the second link. It will only hit direct children of the `.text` class.

Comment: Interesting function, this. Sadly this doesn't fix this particular issue, but I did learn something new :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I realized later what it was that you were really after. But I thought I'd let the answer stay anyway. Glad you liked it, though (:

Answer (score 0):

there’s `a:link` for this:

```
a { /* styles for all anchors */ }
a:link, a:visited { /* styles only for links */ }
a:hover { /* styles that should only apply to hovered links (not anchors) */ }
```

Comment: Sorry, this does nothing differently than the .text a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

adding an anchor element without giving it an id will not make navigation easier. It's also less likely to be valid.  I think what you want is to have anchors that point to the ID of the h3. Something like:

```
<div class="linktotext">
<a href="#title1">Title</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <h3 id="title1">Title</h3>
    Lorem ipsum <a href="otherpage.aspx">dolor</a> sit amet.
</div>
```

Now the anchor in the first part links to the id in the second part.

Second,

To fix your specific issue, you can simply specify the CSS for `a` elements inside of `h3` elements, like this:

```
.text 
{
    color: #000;
}

.text a
{
    color: #ea2026;  //red
}

.text h3 a, .text h3 a:hover
{
    color: #a9a18c;  //gray
    text-decoration: none;
}
```